# Mysql count days of rain of table

Tags: mysql

I would like to know how many days in a period it rains (rain > 0.1) consulting with mysql.

I use this code, but it gives me back all days, with and without rain

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT City, count(Rain > '0.1') as Total FROM Meteo2 where Data BETWEEN '" . split($_POST["date6"]) ."' AND '" . split($_POST["date7"]) ."' group by City");
```

tks

Answer (score 2):

The function `count()` counts the number of `non-NULL` values.  I think you want `sum()`:

```
select sum(Rain > 0.1)
. . .
```

MySQL treats boolean values as integers, with `0` for false and `1` for true.  So sum does what you want, rather than count.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT City, count(SELECT Rain FROM Meteo2 WHERE Rain > '0.1') as Total FROM Meteo2 where Data BETWEEN '" . split($_POST["date6"]) ."' AND '" . split($_POST["date7"]) ."' group by City");
```

Comment: it would be helpful to add some explanation to what was wrong it how was fixed

Answer (score 0):

sum the rain grouped by city

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT City, SUM(SELECT Rain FROM Meteo2 WHERE Rain > '0.1') as Total FROM Meteo2 where Data BETWEEN '" . split($_POST["date6"]) ."' AND '" . split($_POST["date7"]) ."' GROUP BY City");
```